# SASS - reference parent of parent

Tags: css, sass

I'm trying to keep my code as DRY as possible. Consider this example:

```
#parent {
  position: relative;

  #child {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;  
  }
}
```

Now I want to add a hover effect on the `#parent` that will alter the `#child`. I know I can do it like this:

```
#parent {
  position: relative;

  #child {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;   
  }

  &:hover #child {
    transform: scale(1.2, 1.2);
  }
}
```

But I'm not happy with this solution. It isn't completely DRY because `#child` is declared twice. Another way to do it is like this:

```
#parent {
  position: relative;
}

#child {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;

  #parent:hover & {
    transform: scale(1.2, 1.2);
  }  
}
```

This is arguably more semantic, but no more DRY because `#parent` is declared twice.

Is there a truly DRY way to do this with SASS?

Comment: how does the second example work? haven't seen this way before...

Comment: @marczking apologies, I made a mistake in my second example which I've fixed now.

Comment: How would `#child #parent` work in the second example?

Comment: Nope...that's what you have to do...

Comment: @OmriAharon Godamnit, I had the `:hover` in the wrong bit. The second example is correct now. The ampersand references the parent of the scope, so it will render out as `#parent:hover #child`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have minimum of 5 beautiful ways to do it. i will share 1, if you want more i can share more as well.

## Using Functions

```
@mixin onParentHover() {
  $rootString: #{&};
  $parentIndex: str-index($rootString, " ");
  $parent: str_slice($rootString, 0, $parentIndex - 1);
  $children: str_slice($rootString, $parentIndex);

  @at-root #{$parent}:hover #{$children} {
    @content;
  }
}
```

Usage

```
#parent {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  #child {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    @include onParentHover {
      transform: scale(1.2, 1.2);
    }
  }
}
```

## The Final output

```
#parent {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
#parent #child {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
#parent:hover #child {
  text-size: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Now this is a very interesting way to do it. Makes sense! It's a shame there's the overhead of a mixin but I guess it does the job.

Comment: you can use variables with @at-root aswell, check them out in the sass documentation. but i prefer this way because it is much more expressive.

Comment: This is ridiculous useful. My case was I need output like this `.nav #open-btn { /* when nav is not open, show this btn*/` } .nav.nav--open #open-btn {/* when nav is opened, hide this btn */} . So I change the ` @at-root #{$parent}:hover ` on your mixin to ` @at-root #{$parent}.nav--open `. Thank you !

Comment: I'm glad you found it useful!